# Starting cassandra as a service does not work for 2.0.5, sudo cassandra -f works

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

When I try to start cassandra on ubuntu 12.04 (installed via Datastax's `dsc20` package) as a service as follows :

> $ sudo service cassandra start

it says

> *could not access pidfile for Cassandra

& no other messages or anything in logs.

But when I try to run as a root user( `sudo cassandra -f`) it just works properly & cassandra is started. While trying to debug I found that when trying to run *as a non-root user*  I was getting these messages:

```
ERROR 17:48:08,432 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.AssertionError: Directory /var/lib/cassandra/data is not accessible.
..
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/log/cassandra/system.log (Permission denied)
..
java.lang.AssertionError: Directory /var/lib/cassandra/data is not accessible.
```

Is there some problem with the packaging ? Not properly installed/ configured by package ??

Comment: What version of DSE (datastax-enterprise tag) are you using, or is this pure Cassandra?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default the cassandra service does not and should not run as root.

My guess is you ran it in the foreground first, which automatically will create /var/lib/cassandra with root permissions instead of with the cassandra permissions. Either chown -R /var/lib/cassandra with the appropriate group and user or blow away the directory and try starting the service again.

Comment: However is this a practical approach? should I just delete the entire folders as such & let cassandra create new folders ? Wouldn't that reduce some information from cassandra? (like the opscenter keyspaces which were there by default but wont be created by cassandra itself ? or anything else I dont know!).

Comment: Practical approach is a big conversation. Ideally you're starting the service as it's user on a new install and not using root (where you went off the rails there). chown will work if you're concerned about retaining data.

Comment: `sudo chown -R cassandra:cassandra /var/lib/cassandra` worked for me - thx

Answer (score 0):

```
$ su cassandra
```

then run

```
$ service cassandra start
```

It works for me.