# Ubuntu 14.04 Cassandra fails to start but has no error?

Tags: cassandra

Can anyone help me debug this?

`root@xxx:~# service cassandra start
root@xxx:~# service cassandra status
* Cassandra is not running`

I looked in the /var/log/cassandra/system.log file but there is nothing.

I can't figure out why this service doesn't start. :(

Comment: Try running it manually: `cassandra -p cassandra.pid`  If Cassandra has errors related to your Java install, the probably won't make it to your system.log.

Comment: Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7u25 or later.

Comment: Have you set the appropriate user resource limits? http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installRecommendSettings.html?scroll=reference_ds_sxl_gf3_2k__user-resource-limits

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by upgrading to Java 8. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/508546/howto-upgrade-java-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You're running cassandra as root. That could be the problem: [Starting cassandra as a service does not work for 2.0.5, sudo cassandra -f works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308048/starting-cassandra-as-a-service-does-not-work-for-2-0-5-sudo-cassandra-f-works)

If you want to start cassandra as root you can use the -R option. If nothing will work, you can start cassandra with /etc/YOURCASSANDRAPATH/bin/cassandra -R

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.

`al@xxx:~$ service cassandra start
/etc/init.d/cassandra: 71: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)

/etc/init.d/cassandra: 72: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)

al@xxx:~$ start-stop-daemon: unable to set gid to 115 (Operation not permitted)`

If I use sudo then the same result as root. Just nothing happens. :(

Comment: have you found any solution?